# getting post author in laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

In blade way when we have relation between posts and users we can retrieve post author like `{{$post->user->name}}` now I am using `vue` and I want to do the same like `{{post.user.name}}` but it doesn't return author info.

it gives me this errors in console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

## code

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                posts: []
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.load()
        },
        methods: {
            load: function() {
                axios.get('/api/posts')
                .then(
                    response => {
                        this.posts=  (response.data.posts);
                    }     
                )
                .catch(function (error) {
                    this.errors.push(error);
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

any idea?

## UPDATE

`user model`

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

`Post model`

```
public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

`Controller`

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        return response()->json([
            "posts" => $posts
        ], 200);
    }
```

Comment: can you share with us your method, please ? you can't do the  relationship mechanism within vue component

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih the script i shared is pretty much all of it, relations are made by models.

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih I shared my relations

Comment: yes, I know, you just need to specify what you want a return to your vue component as data. the posts object that you return to your component don't have a name

Comment: just want to get my user `name` column to show it as author of the post

Comment: your relationship is correct, can you show me the method that return posts data please within your controller ?

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177869/discussion-between-thamer-belfkih-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I expect, you must return posts data like this :

Ps: update it with your own posts fields.

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();

         return $posts->map(function($post) {
            return [
                 'id' => $post->id,
                'title' => $post->title,
                'description' => $post->description,
                'user' => $post->user->name
            ];
        });
    }
```

and your component must be edited :

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                posts: []
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.load()
        },
        methods: {
            load: function() {
                axios.get('/api/posts')
                .then(
                    response => {
                        this.posts=  (response.data);
                    }     
                )
                .catch(function (error) {
                    this.errors.push(error);
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: so you mean each column of my post table i should include in return? is right now doing the same, can't i just somehow attach user data to it?

Comment: @can join me in chat room please